# Give A Report when Unsuccesfull update database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm very new in PHP programming. I have a code for update database value with 2 condition. Here is my code.

```
<?php
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("");

$id = $_REQUEST["id"];
$serial_number = $_REQUEST["serial_number"];
$email = $_REQUEST["email"];
$nama = $_REQUEST["nama"];
$password = $_REQUEST["password"];


/*** Check Email Exists ***/
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM iot WHERE email = '".$email."' AND id != '".$id."'";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
$objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);
if($objResult)
{
    $arr['StatusID'] = "0"; 
    $arr['Error'] = "Email Exists!";    
    echo json_encode($arr);
    exit();
}

/*** Update ***/
$strSQL = " UPDATE iot SET
    email = '".$email."'
    ,nama = '".$nama."'
    ,password = '".$password."'
    WHERE id = '".$id."' AND serial_number = '".$serial_number."'
";

$objQuery = mysqli_query($objConnect,$strSQL);
if(!$objQuery)
{
    $arr['Report'] = "Cannot save data!";   
}
else
{
    $arr['Report'] = "Saved";   
}

mysql_close($objConnect);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

What i want is if one of two condition not meet, then it will show a report " Cannot Save Data".
Sorry for my bad english.
Cheers.

Comment: If you can, you should refactor your code to use `PDO`.

Comment: may yo explain how to do it?

Comment: Using `pdo::prepare` you should write your SQL in a way that can be called multiple times, passing an array of your variables to `pdo:execute`.